# "Injecting" MySQL Data into application

Tags: c#, mysql

My application is based on MySQL database and it requires "MySql.Data.dll" file to run or else it will crash. Installing MySQL Connector on my computer will allow me to run it without previously mentioned file, only my application (standalone).

Is there a way to "inject" it(mysql.data.dll) to the application so there is no need to have additional files to run?

I'm using Microsoft's Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Install `Costura.Fody` nuget package

Comment: You might be able to add a dll if you make a installer for your program ( https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f640e108-ba23-47bd-94f0-71b8fdca9dfc/how-to-include-dlls-referenced-by-the-project-in-the-installer-build-with-devenvexe-?forum=winformssetup )